# How to remove a whitespace from a string

Tags: python, string

What I want my code to do is that eventually the `"-"` will collide with the `"0"`. But right now all it does is keep chasing the `"0"` and never touch it.

```
import time
global gunshot, gun
gun = 0
gunshot = "-           0"

while True:
    global gunshot
    gunshot = " " + gunshot
    gunshot.replace(' 0', '0')
    print ('\r {0}'.format(gunshot)),
    if gunshot.find("-0") == 1:
        gunshot = "-"
    time.sleep(.1)
```

That is want I want:

```
     -     0
      -    0
       -   0
```

This is what it is doing

```
     -     0
     -     0
     -     0
```

Comment: You are replacing the space but not assigning the result into gunshot. Gunshot = gunshot.replace()

Comment: oh thanks i just noticed

Comment: You don't need to [declare global variables like that](https://docs.python.org/faq/programming.html#what-are-the-rules-for-local-and-global-variables-in-python): `global gunshot, gun`. That makes only sense if you are in a function and want to modify a `gunshot` and `gun` variable (which are outside of your function).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace returns a new string, it does not change the variable inplace.

```
gunshot = gunshot.replace(' 0', '0')
```

This will fix your immediate problem, but you should consider using @MSeiferts code because it is much better.

Comment: how do i change variable inplace?

Comment: You can't change a string in-place in Python but you can reassign the variable name.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) and [`str.rjust`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rjust) function here:

```
bullet = '-'
target = 'O'

distance = 3
field = 10

while distance >= 0:
    print('{}{}{}'.format(bullet, ' '*distance, target).rjust(field))
    distance -= 1
```

which prints:

```
     -   O
      -  O
       - O
        -O
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a deque and just rotate the values:

```
from collections import deque


def gunshot_path(distance):
    return deque(['-'] + ([''] * (distance - 1)))


def print_gunshot_path(distance, target="0"):
    path = gunshot_path(distance)
    for i in range(distance):
        print(" ".join(path) + target)
        path.rotate()


print_gunshot_path(5)
print_gunshot_path(10, target='X')
```

Which prints:

```
-    0
 -   0
  -  0
   - 0
    -0
-         X
 -        X
  -       X
   -      X
    -     X
     -    X
      -   X
       -  X
        - X
         -X
```